# Convolution of Two Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

I have been working a few hours on this particular problem. Please excuse my lack of formatting.

This is the question: Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with density function $f(x) = 2x$ on $[0, 1]$ and $0$ otherwise.

(a)  Calculate the density function $X^2$.

(b) Using the convolution product, calculate the density of $X^2 + X$.

Comment: Why do you need random variable $Y$?

Comment: I do not know.  I was thinking the same thing.  Assume Y can be ignored and it's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$
F_X(x)=2\int_0^xs\mathrm ds=x^2.
$$
Hence,
$F_{X^2}(x)=\Pr\{X^2\le x\}=F_{X}(\sqrt x)=x$ and the density function $f_{X^2}(x)=1$.

I'm not sure how to use the convolution product to calculate the density of $X^2+X$, but I suggest the following approach. Let us observe that $y=x^2+x$ is a monotone function when $0\le x\le 1$ and $x=1/2(\sqrt{4y+1}-1)$. Then we obtain the cumulative distribution function
\begin{align*}
F_{X^2+X}(x)
&=\Pr\{X^2+X\le x\}\\
&=\Pr\{X\le1/2(\sqrt{4x+1}-1)\}\\
&=1/4(\sqrt{4x+1}-1)^2\\
&=1/2(2x+1-\sqrt{4x+1})
\end{align*}
and the density function
$$
f_{X^2+X}(x)=1-\frac1{\sqrt{4x+1}}.
$$